# why my form does not pass value?

Tags: php, html, forms, post

Please help me to figure out my error. It seems to be correct but I can't get the values inside my form.

```html
<form action="validate.php" id="form">
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
      <input type="text" name="name" class="transparent form-group col-sm-5 col-xs-offset-1" placeholder="Name" required><br>
      <input type="text" name="company" class="transparent form-group col-sm-6" placeholder="Company" required>
      <input type="text" name="contact" class="transparent form-group col-sm-5 col-xs-offset-1" placeholder="Contact No." required>
      <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message" rows="4" cols="54" required></textarea>   
      <input type="image" src="img/send_btn.png" alt="Submit" class="pull-right">
</form>
```

validate.php

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];
$content = $_POST['message'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$contact = $_POST['contact'];
?>
```

Comment: You forgot to set the form method to POST

Comment: ohw! yeah yeah your right :)
thanks thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form does not have a "method" specified, and will default to GET. Your validate.php file will only accept methods via POST. Try changing your form definition:

```
<form action="validate.php" id="form" method="POST">
```